# How can i take a user dump using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, dump, coredump

I want to take  user dump of a process using powershell How can i do it?
The same I get on rightclicking the process in Taskmanager

Answer (score 10):

*Based on [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20210724080608/https://risksense.com/blog/hidden-gems-in-windows-the-hunt-is-on/) (archived) from Risksense.*
`MiniDump` function from native `comsvcs.dll` Windows dll could be used.

Like:

```
Powershell -c rundll32.exe C:\Windows\System32\comsvcs.dll, MiniDump {ID-of-the-process} $Env:TEMP\my_dump_file.bin full
```

Comment: Note that the dump file path cannot have spaces (quoting doesn't work). For the directory part of the path, one can work around by setting the current directory (or specify argument -WorkingDirectory for `Start-Process`) so we only have to pass the filename of the dump file to rundll32.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use [Procdump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) from Sysinternals toolkit. Use `Get-Process` to get process id, which you can pass to Procdump for actual dumping.

**Edit:**

I'd still rather use readily available tools instead of the hard way. Have you got a valid business reason? Since you insist, there is a [Win32 API call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that creates user mode memory dumps. It can be invoked from [.Net code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dondu/archive/2010/10/24/writing-minidumps-in-c.aspx), so either use P/Invoke or embed C# into your Powershell code. This is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Is there a way to do it using some internal commands of Powershell or cmd or using wmi:?

Comment: I wanted to have this because I need this script to run on a number of different Machines. and I dont want to install them on each of them .

Comment: How to use `procdump` to collect a core on demand, i.e., now instead of waiting the process to crash or something else ?

Comment: Forensics and reverse engineering would be a practical usecase -- a lot of malware checks for the Sysinternals suite of tools. Also, your response does a great job at not actually answering the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar use case where I needed to create a dump for an IIS process.  Granted I could have used [DebugDiag](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924), but I ended up going down this path.  Here's what I used (*and works pretty well, I should add*):

```
$procid = Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.ProcessName -eq 'w3wp'} | Select-Object ProcessName,Id
New-Item -Path "c:\temp\Dumps" -Type directory -Force
cmd.exe /c "c:\temp\procdump64.exe" $procid.id -accepteula -mp "c:\temp\Dumps"
```

Furthermore, you could use these dump files for analysis using DebugDiag too.  So it's a win-win in my opinion.

> PS: Theoretically, one could also get the Process ID using the `Get-CimInstance` cmdlet.  So something like this would also work:
>
> `Get-CimInstance -Query "SELECT * from Win32_Process WHERE name LIKE 'w3wp%'"`

Answer (score 0):

Hi sorry I'm not much help. I've never used a DUP file before. But there is a WMI class called Win32_Process:

```
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Process
```

Not sure if that's the info you are looking for. Has different properties than Get-Process.

Comment: Win32_product looks like a typo to me. In addition, Win32_process does provide you a handle for process, but not a way to create a memory dump for one.