# Windows Task Manager - Create dump file in command line

Tags: windows, command-line, dump, production, taskmanager

In Windows, using the Task Manager, we can right click on a process and Create dump file to export all threads state and memory usage to a file. I use it to debug some programs that are deployed in production environment.

I would like to be able to call this feature using the command line. Is it possible and how? I want to do that **without having to install a third party software**

Comment: I don't think you can do this without an external app, look at procdump, it's a standalone app so won't need installing as such.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523460/how-can-i-take-a-user-dump-using-powershell